# Eclipse Plugin Code Completion

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I writes an Eclipse plugin that propose code completion. The mechanism itself work fine but it's the data for the completion that i can't get dynamically.

I mean that i needs to parse the java code written by the user in his project.
To resolve this problem, i have try to use reflexion. But this does not work in OSGI environment.

I also tried the Reflection Api, with it, i have successfully find the methods annotated but i failed to retrieve method parameters and their Javadoc.

So i have to find a way to retrieve, all methods with their Javadoc, annotated with some annotations.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Look at the [Eclipse JDT Abstract Syntax Tree](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html)

Comment: Nice. I was not aware of this Eclipse part. This is what i need.